# GMaps don't load at first open page, after reload it works

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I use gmaps4rails gem and maps are not always loaded at first page open, after reload it works.

[image]

So, my code
**show.html.haml**

```
    %script{:src => "//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.13&sensor=false&libraries=geometry", :type => "text/javascript"}
    %script{:src => "//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js", :type => "text/javascript"}

........

    .col-lg-8.col-sm-8.col-md-8.col-xs-12
        #map
        %br/

......

    :javascript
        handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
        handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
            markers = handler.addMarkers(#{raw @hash.to_json});
            handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
            handler.fitMapToBounds();
            handler.getMap().setZoom(16);
        });
```

in **parks_controller.rb**

```
  def show
    set_park
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@park) do |park, marker|
      marker.lat park.latitude
      marker.lng park.longitude
      marker.infowindow park.address
    end
```

in **index.html.haml**

```
 - @parks.each do |park|
    .map_index
      .image_wrapper
        = image_tag "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x200&sensor=false&zoom=16&markers=#{park.latitude}%2C#{park.longitude}", class: "map_image"
      %h2
        = link_to park.title, park
```

Working app - https://geoparks.herokuapp.com/

Tell me, please, what to change or add to code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just add to links that goes to the maps page parameter

```
'data-no-turbolink' => true
```

Code `= link_to p.title, park`in **index.html.haml** changed to

```
= link_to park.title, park, 'data-no-turbolink' => true
```

Comment: I can't tell how much pain turbolinks has caused me already.. The little use it brought is no reason to keep it in an app at all..